# Js cors. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, cors

Everything is good - when i send request like this :

```
function toServer2(url, type, data, success) {
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open(type, url, true);     
xhr.send();}
```

415 response - when i send request like this :

```
function toServer2(url, type, data, success) {
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open(type, url, true);     
xhr.send(data);} // data = "{'name': 'Ben', count: 12}"
```

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' - when i send request like this:

```
function toServer2(url, type, data, success) {
var XHR = ("onload" in new XMLHttpRequest()) ? XMLHttpRequest : XDomainRequest;

var xhr = new XHR();
xhr.open(type, url, true);   

xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

xhr.send(data);} // data = "{'name': 'Ben', count: 12}"
```

Comment: Sorry for my English

Comment: Ask a clear question

Comment: Why show exception < No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' ...> when i added xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');

Comment: full exception:XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:33649/api/items. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:33607' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: The URL you are requesting is on a different port than the page which is making the AJAX request. You can send a header on the server to allow CORS, see the related questions on the right to see examples.

Comment: xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); // this ? if 'yes' then its dont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server that receives the AJAX call must send the CORS header within the response, as it's on a different port.  Check this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/